# Can not access property of jobject

Tags: c#, json.net

I fetch data from a geo location provider.

```
var data = JObject.Parse(json);
```

data is the below JObject.

```
{{
  "postalCodes": [
    {         
      "lng": 9.15,          
      "lat": 48.7
    }
  ]
}}
```

When I try `data["postalCodes"]` I get another object but I can not find "lat or "lng" properties.

Doing `data["postalCodes"]["lat"]` does not work.

How can I get lat properties value?

Comment: Is the double `{{` at the start and end correct? I think that may be the problem

Comment: but from where come the double curls?

Comment: I think the problem is in the `{{`. It threw an exception when I tried to parse your JSON string.

Comment: The double curls do come most likely because you've copied it from the debugger. Can it be?

Comment: @FerhatSayan haha yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
data["postalCodes"][0]["lat"]
```

or:

```
data["postalCodes"].First["lat"]
```

Because it is an array, so you have to say you want the first object in the array.

As Rhumborl mentioned, you should always validate your JSON. Have a look here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
{
  "postalCodes": [
    {         
      "lng": 9.15,          
      "lat": 48.7
    }
  ]
}
```